# initState not being called

Tags: flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

i am using standard flutter app to integrate firebase cloud messaging. Everything works, except the `initState` implementation of the state that should setup the firebase callback handlers.

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  // Firebase messaging
  FirebaseMessaging _firebaseMessaging = FirebaseMessaging();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    firebaseCloudMessagingListeners();
    print('Starting state');
  }
...
```

I am not able to see any debug print in the console (i am using Android Studio).

I think i am doing something wrong, but can't understand what.

Comment: can you trying putting the print before the `firebaseCloudMessagingListeners()`? Also sometimes if you hotreload not all the widgets get rerendered so try to hotrestart instead if you're doing that

Comment: i think you don't need to call a firebase method at the initState, firebase works with streams  its reactive, please update the question with more details, or if you don't have been using StreamBuilder  for firebase calls, please try it first.

Comment: Nevermind, guys. It was all working, only the Android Studio log was messed up. Thanks all.

Comment: @BrunoRipa nice to solved, still I suggest you to execute your firebaselistener when application is starting, not in `initState`.

Comment: @EsenMehmet thanks for the suggestion, appreciated !